# PCRE regular expression to match text except word group

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm struggling to adjust my regex to filter out

- rlwrap
- bash

from:

```
cat file  
user   30300 29384  0 Mar05 pts/4    00:00:00 /opt/bin/rlwrap /opt/test/l64/app apps/bin -gw :1234 -p 10006  
user   30301 30300  0 Mar05 pts/5    00:00:00 /opt/test/l64/app apps/bin -gw :1234 -p 10006  
user   30300 29384  0 Mar05 pts/4    00:00:00 /opt/bin/bash /opt/test/l64/app apps/bin -gw :1234 -p 10006
```

So I need to get only second row:

```
grep -P 'regex' file  
user   30301 30300  0 Mar05 pts/5    00:00:00 /opt/test/l64/app apps/bin -gw :1234 -p 10006
```

what I have is:

```
grep -P '((?:(?!rlwrap\b|bash\b).)*?)-p 10006$' file
```

But it doesn't work :(

I need only PCRE regex, I need to make it working withing this **grep -P** statement.
So please no awk, perl, sed, grep -v or similar.

**EDIT**
I'm really wondering why someone down-voted this question?

Comment: Why can't you do multiple passes with `grep`, using `-v` on a later invocation?

Comment: Because application which will use this regex is not an application which invokes other applications and takes PCRE regex as regex to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find all lines that don't contain `/rlwrap` or `/bash` followed by a space:

```
grep -P '^(?!.*/(rlwrap|bash) )' file
```

Comment: Perfect! '^' did the trick I've ended up with:  
'^(?!.*/(rlwrap\b|bash\b)).*-p 10006$'